# stop postback from happening from cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is validating some fields from `cs` page, if `txtRedirectSource == txtRedirectLocation` I want to stop the function execution- something like:
`e.preventDefault()` in jquery.

```
public int GetHtml() 
{
     if (txtRedirectSource.Equals(txtRedirectLocation))
     {
        // e.preventDefault();
        // return false;
     }

     .... // the function continue
     .....
}
```

I tried to use `return` and to `Throw` an exception - but those ended up with a postback which I don't want to happen

Comment: No, you're executing a server side event.  The server needs to execute, which causes a post back.  The closest you can get, would be model binding.  Where the binded model is validated, before the post back physically occurs.  Look at the model binder section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: By the way, that's not a "cs page", that's an ASPX page.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, that is an excellent point also.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto this is actually a `cs` page with no aspx page

Comment: @Greg your answer is good and if you'll post it as an answer I will accept it. I will look for a way to do it `client side`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if it was a `aspx` page and all of this code was in the `cs` `code-behind` page I would have simply use a `client` way to do it, from the start.

Comment: @E.Meir I've added an answer and some additional information to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this occurs, is because your executing a server side event.  Once the server executes, then it will render the page based on request.  The closest you can get would be model binding, this causes the binder model to be validated before the post back occurs.

More detail can be found here on [model binders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405(v=vs.98).aspx).

To illustrate server side event processing, a snippet:

> There are several server-side technologies that can be used when
>   developing web applications. The most popular is Microsoft’s ASP.NET.
>   In ASP.NET, server-side code uses the .NET Framework and is written in
>   languages like C# and VB.NET. Server-side processing is used to
>   interact with permanent storage like databases or files. The server
>   will also render pages to the client and process user input.
>   Server-side processing happens when a page is first requested and when
>   pages are posted back to the server. Examples of server-side
>   processing are user validation, saving and retrieving data, and
>   navigating to other pages.
>
> The disadvantage of server-side processing is the page postback: it
>   can introduce processing overhead that can decrease performance and
>   force the user to wait for the page to be processed and recreated.
>   Once the page is posted back to the server, the client must wait for
>   the server to process the request and send the page back to the
>   client.